# Using ng-required with model's value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to validate my form. In one field, I have to validate it null &  it's value. How can I do this?

By the way, I don't write a function for this on controller.

```
<form name="frm">
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-required="myModel != '' || myModel != undefined || myModel != 'xxx'" />
<button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" >Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `ng-required` only because it checks if the value was entered or not. In your case you can use `ng-required` to cover this statements: `myModel != '' || myModel != undefined`. And if you want to check that `myModel` value isn't `'xxx'` you should use `ng-pattern` directive. Appropriate regex for your case should be: `/^(xxx.+|(?!xxx).*)$/`.

```
<form name="frm">
   <input type="text" ng-model="myModel" ng-pattern="/^(xxx.+|(?!xxx).*)$/" ng-required="" />
   <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" >Send</button>
</form>
```

[Check documentation about directives components for input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).